# How POPULARITY percent number works in pubdev?

Tags: flutter, dart

I read this from their doc https://pub.dev/help/scoring

> Popularity:
>
> It is a measure of how many developers use a package, providing insight into what other developers are using.
>
> Popularity measures the number of apps that depend on a package over the past 60 days. We show this on a normalized scale from 100% (the most used package) to 0% (the least used package), but are investigating if we can provide absolute usage counts in a future version.
>
> Although this score is based on actual download counts, it compensates for automated tools such as continuous builds that fetch the package on each change request.

But I would like to know if after those 60 days, the old download counts are lost. If so, that means popularity number will get down too. Can I say that ?

Answer (score 5):

IMHO Yes. That is reasonable - if a package is outdated and people do not like to use it, then it is not that popular *now* even if it was.